# How to query user status (Active or Deactivated) via Stack Overflow Rest API?

Tags: api, rest

I'm trying to get a report of all Stack Overflow users via Rest API and need to get the status of user (active or deactivated).

However from the response of user Rest API, I cannot find a field representing such info. [response of user API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K4xu.png)

The URL of users Rest API is: https://stackoverflow.internal.xxx.com/api/2.2/users

Is it possible to query user status (Active or Deactivated) via Stack Overflow Rest API?

Thanks,
Yuanquan

Answer (score 0):

@yuanquman In stackoverflow deactivation is related to teams: link for reference: https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387795-deactivate-or-reactivate-users

there's an option to delete the account though : Link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

So User api will give you details of the users which are present and not yet deleted. You can sort them as per the activity or date created.You can refer this page for complex query careation : https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max

In case you want to get the details for a particular user you can use this api : https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/userId . Replace the user id with the userId of the user you want to see. Hope it answers your doubt.

Comment: Thanks TheFirstOne for your input. I checked the API https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/userId but cannot find a field which indicates whether a user is active or deactivated.

Comment: As per my understanding, any deactivated user will not show up in the https://stackoverflow.internal.xxx.com/api/2.2/users